# How to use slug to redirect a user to a different page using wp_redirect()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to redirect users to the form page if they have not yet filled it so that if they visit the pages in my conditions, they can be redirected to back to fill the form first.

I have been able to redirect other pages properly but I'm having an issue with a page that contains a parameter.

The link https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=booknetic

I tried:

```
//Redirect user back to application form if they have not filled it
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_logged_in' );
  function redirect_if_user_logged_in() {
  if ( is_front_page() || isset($_GET['page']) || is_page('profile') || is_page('account')  
   && is_user_logged_in() && $count == 0) {
    wp_redirect( '/first-time-application-temp/'); 
     exit;
   }
}
```

AND

```
//Redirect user back to application form if they have not filled it
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_logged_in' );
  function redirect_if_user_logged_in() {
  if ( is_front_page() || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=booknetic' || is_page('profile') || is_page('account')  
   && is_user_logged_in() && $count == 0) {
    wp_redirect( '/first-time-application-temp/'); 
     exit;
   }
}
```

`is_front_page()`, and `is_page('profile')` || `is_page('account') && is_user_logged_in() && $count == 0)`

Note* `$count` is a global variable that checks whether the user had an entry in the form.

How do I test whether the `is_page == wp-admin/admin.php?page=booknetic` ?

Could it be failing because the menu link is just a custom link that redirects to the page `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=booknetic` which is an existing page created by another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_logged_in' );
function redirect_if_user_logged_in() {
    if ( (is_front_page() || isset($_GET['page']) || is_page('profile') || is_page('account') ) && is_user_logged_in() && $count == 0) {
        wp_redirect( '/first-time-application-temp/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

OR

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_logged_in' );
function redirect_if_user_logged_in() {
    if ( ( is_front_page() || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=booknetic' || is_page('profile') || is_page('account') ) && is_user_logged_in() && $count == 0) {
        wp_redirect( '/first-time-application-temp/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: The redirect is working to the target page. The issue is with my condition for the link https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=booknetic. If I visit say, the other pages as indicated in my condition, for example, profile, it will successfully redirect to the target page ```/first-time-application-temp/```.

Comment: I could not tell the difference between the answer you gave and what I tried in my question.

Comment: The ( ) between the || elements.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The particular link is created by another plugin. So what I did is I added a quick access link to the menu as a link to redirect the user. All the menu links with pages I created myself such as Profile, Account work perfectly. I just can;t quite tell why this particular one isn't working.